# Python output file formatting - text

Tags: python

This is my first post so please be gentle, im trying to write two text files generated from some user input, the file "hostname - VLAN_config" is fine, i use that file elsewhere in my code, what i do need however is another file (in this case "hostname - Trunk_config" to be formatted in a certain manner in order to use it for another part of my code.

The below code produces a file that looks like this;
", 1, 2, 3"

but i need it to generate a text file that looks like;
1, 2, 3

```
print ('VLANS')
print('-----------------------------------------------')
print(' ')
condition = True
while (condition == True):
    vlan = raw_input('Specify a VLAN id: ')
    name = raw_input('What name for this VLAN: ')
    print(' ')
    with open(hostname + ' - VLAN_config', "ab") as f:
        f.write('vlan ' + vlan)
        f.write('\n')
        f.write('name ' + name)
        f.write('\n')
    with open(hostname + ' - Trunk_config', "ab") as f:
        f.write(', ' + vlan)
    test = raw_input('Would you like to add another? [Y] ')
    if test == (''):
        condition = True
    elif test == ('n'):
        condition = False
    else:
        test = raw_input('Invalid input, more?')
        if test == ('y'):
            condition = True
        elif test == ('n'):
            condition = False
```

any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you displeased with the leading comma, or are you getting strings and want a sequence of numbers instead?

Comment: The function that I want to use the text for does not allow the leading “,” or a trailing one either

Comment: How about processing the text to strip off the leading or trailing white space and commas?  You can call something like `str1.strip(' ,')` before you pass the string into the function.  lstrip() gets rid of leading chars, and rstrip() gets rid of trailing chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only problem is the first comma? Why don't you add a test to check if you are writing the first value?

Other solution: write `', '` only after the user said they want to add another input.